# Is it possible to dynamically update the IntentFilter of a BroadcastReceiver defined in the manifest?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am trying to dynamically update the intentfilter for aBroadcastReceiver that is defined in the manifest. The intents are declared in an API that is outside of my app.

The end goal is to have these actions perform in the background if the app is closed, but my BroadcastReceiver dynamically created throws a leak error message if I leave the app without un-registering it.

Am I going about this the right way? Is it possible to dynamically update things declared in the manifest?

How the intents are declared in the API:

```
public static final String RECEIVED_MESSAGE = Constants.NAMESPACE_PREFIX +
        ".action." + "RECEIVED_MESSAGE";
public static final String SEND_MESSAGE = Constants.NAMESPACE_PREFIX +
        ".action." + "SEND_MESSAGE";
public static final String MESSAGE_SENT = Constants.NAMESPACE_PREFIX +
        ".action." + "MESSAGE_SENT";
public static final String MESSAGE_NOT_SENT = Constants.NAMESPACE_PREFIX +
        ".action." + "MESSAGE_NOT_SENT";

public static final String[] ALL = new String[] { RECEIVED_MESSAGE, SEND_MESSAGE, MESSAGE_SENT,
        MESSAGE_NOT_SENT };
```

How I creating the Intentfilter :

```
private IntentFilter createIntentFilter()
{
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    for(String action : MessageActions.ALL)
        filter.addAction(action);

    return filter;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change these intent filters at runtime. The only thing you can really change is which components are enabled. At best you probably need to run a `Service` in the background which will register and hold onto the dynamic `BroadcastReceiver`.

Given the code you posted, I don't see why these cannot be used in a statically defined `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest. Unless `Constants.NAMESPACE_PREFIX` is not a compile-time constant expression, all of these strings are compile-time constants that you should be able to use in your AndroidManifest (albeit hardcoded there since you can't reference anything Java).

Comment: Was trying to minimise battery consumption by having as few background services as possible. Guess I will just have to hardcode the intent filter. 
Cheers for the response!